# Deducing $\pi$ is irrational from the form of a polynomial in $\pi$.

Tags: integration, polynomials, irrational-numbers

> For each non-negative integer $n$ let
>   $I_n(\theta)=\int^1_{-1}(1-x^2)^ncos(\theta x) dx$. Prove that
>   ${\theta}^2I_n=2n(2n − 1)I_{n-1}−4n(n−1)I_{n-2}$ for all $n\ge2$, and
>   hence that
>   ${\theta}^{2n+1}I_n(\theta)=n!(P_n(\theta)sin(θ)+Q_n(\theta)cos(\theta))$
>   for some pair $P_n$ and $Q_n$ of polynomials of degree at most $2n$
>   with integer coefficients.
>
> Deduce that $\pi$ is irrational.

I've done most of the question but I'm just struggling with the final deduction. I've set $\theta=\pi$ to obtain $\pi^{2n+1}I_n(\pi)+n!Q_n(\pi)=0$, this is clearly a polynomial in $\pi$ of degree $2n+1$ with integer coefficients. I was thinking it may help to show that $I_n(\pi)$ is irrational, but beyond this I'm not sure.

Thank you

Comment: Suppose $\pi/2 = a/b$ is rational, then set $\theta = \pi/2$.

Comment: for broadening your culture, see the (hopefully shortest) proof of irrationnality of $\pi$ in (https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183510788)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [Cartwright's proof of the irrationality of $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_%CF%80_is_irrational#Cartwright.27s_proof). Put $\theta=\frac\pi2$ and obtain
$$
\theta^{2n+1}I_n(\theta)=n!P_n(\theta).\tag1
$$
If $\theta=\frac ab$ is rational, then rearranging (1) gives
$$
{a^{2n+1}\over n!}I_n(a/b) = b^{2n+1}P_n(a/b).\tag2
$$
Note that the RHS of (2) is an integer, since $P_n$ has degree at most $2n$. Now look at the LHS. Notice that $I_n(a/b)$ lies between $0$ and $2$ for any $n$ (since the integrand is positive and bounded by $1$), while the expression $a^{2n+1}/n!$ gets arbitrarily small as $n\to\infty$. Thus for large enough $n$ we have found an integer between $0$ and $1$, a contradiction.